# How to block someone who redirected his email spams to your email address?

Tags: outlook.com, spam-prevention

I have two friends (yes, believe or not they are my friends) that are redirecting all the email spam they receive to my email address. This makes my Hotmail account receive 30 spams per hour (that are not filtered) so I need to keep erasing them and blocking the sender.

I already blocked their email addresses in the "from sender" configuration (the only "block" option that Hotmail allows me) but because the spam that I receive is not "addressed from" any of my friends' addresses (the emails that I receive actually are addressed to them, not me) I cannot block them.

So, is there some way to block an email with a "sent to" condition?

<sub>P.S. This happens on my Hotmail account but could have happened with any client that I was using - I have never found a "sent to" block method in any email client configuration so I believe this is not a topic for Web Applications or another site.</sub>

Comment: ummmmm you want to block sent to.. sent to on all emails will be you. so just shut down your account and go back to snail mail. ps. google has much better spam filter than hotspam.. erm mail

Comment: lol, I can't close this email, I'm using it for more than 10 years

Comment: You mean you want to block `from` field ... Emails which come from your "friends" and contain images or more than 1-2 links for example...

Comment: They are not your friends.

Comment: "from fields" are easily forge-able and are not validated. Your typical email program is essentially a bot that types text for you into a terminal ( google `telnet smtp` ). You simply type `MAIL FROM: mail@domain.net` and it accepts it no questions asked. Some servers might attempt to validate, but ones that do not are a dime a dozen. Have you determined that your friends do in fact forward spam to you? Have you ensured they don't have trojans or email virus applications installed? Note you are probably on the BCC list, and 100s of people are getting the same thing.

Comment: @horatio: Belive or not, they told me they gonna do that, lol

Comment: Did you check the `Delivery-To` part in the headers of the email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Partial Answer

You can transfer all your mails to gmail and manage your inbox from there. You will have to sacrifice Hotmail for this and use Gmail, if you already have a Gmail account then its good.

Hotmail doesn't have as much setting and customization options as Gmail provides (IMHO), though I haven't use Hotmail so much, so I can't tell more about it.

### Section #1 *(Shifting to Gmail)*

Don't worry, you won't loose any mails from your hotmail account.

#### Step #1

Sign in to your gmail account, If you don't have [then create](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=http://mail.google.com/mail/&ltmpl=default).

#### Step #2

After you are signed in:

- Go to your **settings** (*make sure that you are using standard mode, not basic html*).
- Move to **Accounts and Import** tab.
- Go to the section which says **Check mail from other accounts (using POP3)**
- Click on **Add a POP3 mail account you own**

[image: Gmail Settings]
<sup>Drag and drop image in another tab to see clearly</sup>

#### Step #3

- You will be asked about your email id.
- In next screen, do as directed, but also select the check boxes about SSL and labeling. [image: Adding hotmail to gmail]
- Click on add account. You will be asked some more questions, respond to them as your will. *(they are helpful)*

### Section #2 *(Teaching your friends lesson)*

*Setting up the filter*

#### Step #1

- Go to **Filters** tab of Settings. Now you should see **Create a new filter** at the bottom of the screen.
- As you said, there is a **Send-to** filter.
- Play with setting to get more out of Gmail..

[image: Gmail Filters]